# SSRS - MultiValue Parameter "Select All" Problems

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multivalue

I am using SSRS 2008.

I have a multivalue, text, not blank parameter named personID.  This parameter's available values are set to a dataset (let's call this dataset PersonQuery), which is tied to a stored procedure.  This parameter's default values are also set to PersonQuery.  This was working perfectly where when the page/report loaded all possible values for personID were selected.... then I must have changed something (however, I don't remember changing anything..?) because now it is broken... Everything is still fine locally but not once it's on the server.

When I first noticed it was broken only one of the available values was selected.  So, I decided to try putting ltrim(rtrim(value)) in my stored procedure without changing any names or aliases.... and updated/refreshed the fields in the dataset to be safe and re-deployed the report to the server.  Now, no default values are selected for this parameter when the page loads.

Can anyone suggest anything to try or has any idea about what's going on here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix might be to delete the server version of the report and redeploy/upload your .rdl as a new report. SSRS keeps some of the meta-data about reports when a new definition is uploaded to replace an existing report. This includes some attributes of the parameters. This metadata is removed when a report is deleted from the server.

If you delete the server version of the report, you will lose subscriptions, and may need to reconnect the datasource, but if the report is working locally, then I think this will fix the problem.

Comment: Just going back through my old StackOverflow questions... man, did SSRS make me angry when I was working on it.  I was constantly perplexed with so many weird issues.  This was the ultimate solution, though.  Delete it off the server, rename the thing, re-promote.  This solution probably fixed 80% of my issues.  I think it was because... the back end, the SSRS database, wasn't updating properly.  IIRC, this was  a case-sensitive issue btwn the RDL and the database.  I no longer work with it and I am so grateful for that...